# What is the word for act of monotonously demanding for something (many be a toy) repeatedly?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for act of "demanding for something (many be a toy) repeatedly along with a monotonous sound (not very loudly and not crying)"?

I guess 'whine', 'whimper', or, 'solicit' would not be applicable.

Is that 'nagging'?

Comment: "Normal child", of course.

Comment: The Raineys, *Q&A: The Persistent Child* http://www.familylife.com/articles/topics/parenting/challenges/attitude-problems/qa-the-persistent-child#.U0d4tVL0Rkg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both **nagging** and **pestering** would fit.

> [nag:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nag) to annoy by persistent faultfinding, complaints, or demands.
>
> [pester:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pester) trouble or annoy (someone) with frequent or persistent requests or interruptions

---

And there is a phenomenon called "**[pester power](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pester+power)**":

> the ability possessed by a child to nag a parent relentlessly until the parent succumbs and agrees to the child's request

Answer (score 6):

The verb is *to pester*:

> [***pester***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pester) : *(transitive)* To bother, harass or annoy persistently.

A mother might say to her child, "If you stop *pestering* me about it, I might consider it."

A more protracted and calculated persistent request for something might be called a *campaign*

> [***campaign***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/campaign)  :  a connected series of operations designed to bring about a particular result

Suzy has been *campaigning* to get that doll for two months straight.

Answer (score 2):

The Italians have this great word, *[frignare](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/frignare)*, which describes to a T that low whining, *nenene* whimpering noise that annoying spoilt children often make when they are demanding something, usually attention.

The equivalent in English would be either **whinge** or **whine**.

- Whine *a long, high-pitched complaining cry*
- Whinge *Complain persistently and in a peevish or irritating way*

You could add the two together and say:

> Their three-year-old doesn't stop whinging and whining. She (or he) is driving me nuts

[Whinging and whining](http://www.independent.ie/lifestyle/mothers-babies/we-are-getting-worried-about-our-toddlers-whinging-and-whining-26869299.html)

Comment: Does my answer appear unsympathetic? I actually like kids, but erm... I had the most spoilt niece ever, she only stopped whining when she got into university.

Answer (score 1):

A whining child was called a **carker** but the term is now defined as [burdensome, annoying
Examples of CARKING](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carking)

Answer (score 1):

Consider "badgering" and "begging."

> [badger](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/badger): to ask or tell someone again and again to do something.
>
> [beg](http://dynamo.dictionary.com/73491/reading-changed-my-life-vocabulary/print): to ask (something) in a very serious and emotional way for something needed or wanted very much.

Answer (score 0):

The word I distinctly remember being used most is **craze** . *He keeps crazing me for a baby elephant*.

But I am not sure if that is peculiar to an East Anglian use of *craze*, or if it is normal across the UK.